# Polkadot - tests fail out-of-the-box

Tags: polkadot, testing, unit-tests

How can I make the tests pass?

Steps to reproduce:

1. `git clone https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot`
2. `cd polkadot`
3. `cargo build`
4. `cargo test`

$ cargo test

```
⚡ Found 3 strongly connected components which includes at least one cycle each
cycle(001) ∈ α: DisputeCoordinator ~~{"DisputeDistributionMessage"}~~> DisputeDistribution ~~{"DisputeCoordinatorMessage"}~~>  *
cycle(002) ∈ β: CandidateBacking ~~{"ProvisionerMessage"}~~> Provisioner ~~{"CandidateBackingMessage"}~~>  *
cycle(003) ∈ γ: NetworkBridgeRx ~~{"GossipSupportMessage"}~~> GossipSupport ~~{"NetworkBridgeRxMessage"}~~>  *
    Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 2.15s
     Running unittests src/main.rs (target/debug/deps/polkadot-45cd41598fdd19a5)

running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s

     Running tests/benchmark_block.rs (target/debug/deps/benchmark_block-36e2726cfcdc7e80)

running 1 test
2022-12-01 16:42:50 Essential task `txpool-background` failed. Shutting down service.    
2022-12-01 16:42:50 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:42:50 Block 1 with     2 tx used 212.10% of its weight (    20,145,091 of      9,497,706 ns) - OVER WEIGHT!    
test benchmark_block_works has been running for over 60 seconds
2022-12-01 16:43:57 Essential task `txpool-background` failed. Shutting down service.    
2022-12-01 16:43:57 Essential task `transaction-pool-task-0` failed. Shutting down service.    
2022-12-01 16:43:57 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:43:57 Block 1 with     2 tx used 446.49% of its weight (    46,758,523 of     10,472,472 ns) - OVER WEIGHT!    
2022-12-01 16:44:55 Essential task `txpool-background` failed. Shutting down service.    
2022-12-01 16:44:55 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:44:55 Block 1 with     2 tx used 186.84% of its weight (    16,926,553 of      9,059,511 ns) - OVER WEIGHT!    
2022-12-01 16:45:46 Essential task `txpool-background` failed. Shutting down service.    
2022-12-01 16:45:46 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:45:46 Block 1 with     2 tx used 179.78% of its weight (    14,686,623 of      8,169,364 ns) - OVER WEIGHT!    
test benchmark_block_works ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 231.51s

     Running tests/benchmark_extrinsic.rs (target/debug/deps/benchmark_extrinsic-405b7d564d961c0a)

running 2 tests
2022-12-01 16:45:46 [0]  generated 1 npos voters, 1 from validators and 0 nominators    
2022-12-01 16:45:46 [0]  generated 1 npos targets    
2022-12-01 16:45:46 Took active validators from set with wrong size    
2022-12-01 16:45:46 Took active validators from set with wrong size    
2022-12-01 16:45:46 Took active validators from set with wrong size.    
2022-12-01 16:45:46 Took active validators from set with wrong size    
Error: 
   0: Other: can only use subcommand with --chain [polkadot-dev, kusama-dev, westend-dev, rococo-dev, wococo-dev], got polkadot

Backtrace omitted. Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display it.
Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=full to include source snippets.
Error: 
   0: Other: can only use subcommand with --chain [polkadot-dev, kusama-dev, westend-dev, rococo-dev, wococo-dev], got ksmcc3

Backtrace omitted. Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display it.
Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=full to include source snippets.
Error: 
   0: Other: can only use subcommand with --chain [polkadot-dev, kusama-dev, westend-dev, rococo-dev, wococo-dev], got westend2

Backtrace omitted. Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display it.
Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=full to include source snippets.
Error: 
   0: Other: can only use subcommand with --chain [polkadot-dev, kusama-dev, westend-dev, rococo-dev, wococo-dev], got rococo_v2_2

Backtrace omitted. Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display it.
Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=full to include source snippets.
test benchmark_extrinsic_rejects_non_dev_runtimes ... ok
2022-12-01 16:45:56  Initializing Genesis block/state (state: 0xd6e4…c48c, header-hash: 0x300d…9518)    
2022-12-01 16:45:56  Loading GRANDPA authority set from genesis on what appears to be first startup.    
2022-12-01 16:46:08  Creating empty BABE epoch changes on what appears to be first startup.    
2022-12-01 16:46:08 Essential task `transaction-pool-task-0` failed. Shutting down service.    
2022-12-01 16:46:08 Essential task `txpool-background` failed. Shutting down service.    
2022-12-01 16:46:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:46:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:46:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:46:08 Running 1 warmups...    
2022-12-01 16:46:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:46:08 Executing block 1 times    
2022-12-01 16:46:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:46:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:46:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:46:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:46:08 Building block, this takes some time...    
2022-12-01 16:46:08 Extrinsics per block: 1    
2022-12-01 16:46:08 Running 1 warmups...    
2022-12-01 16:46:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:46:08 Executing block 1 times    
2022-12-01 16:46:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:46:08 Executing a system::remark extrinsic takes[ns]:
Total: 2292161
Min: 2292161, Max: 2292161
Average: 2292161, Median: 2292161, Stddev: 0
Percentiles 99th, 95th, 75th: 2292161, 2292161, 2292161    
2022-12-01 16:46:08 [0]  generated 1 npos voters, 1 from validators and 0 nominators    
2022-12-01 16:46:08 [0]  generated 1 npos targets    
2022-12-01 16:46:08 Took active validators from set with wrong size    
2022-12-01 16:46:08 Took active validators from set with wrong size    
2022-12-01 16:46:08 Took active validators from set with wrong size.    
2022-12-01 16:46:08 Took active validators from set with wrong size    
2022-12-01 16:46:19  Initializing Genesis block/state (state: 0xd6e4…c48c, header-hash: 0x300d…9518)    
2022-12-01 16:46:19  Loading GRANDPA authority set from genesis on what appears to be first startup.    
2022-12-01 16:46:30  Creating empty BABE epoch changes on what appears to be first startup.    
2022-12-01 16:46:30 Essential task `txpool-background` failed. Shutting down service.    
2022-12-01 16:46:30 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:46:30 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:46:30 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:46:30 Running 1 warmups...    
2022-12-01 16:46:30 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:46:30 Executing block 1 times    
2022-12-01 16:46:30 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:46:30 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:46:30 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:46:30 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:46:30 Building block, this takes some time...    
2022-12-01 16:46:30 Extrinsics per block: 1    
2022-12-01 16:46:30 Running 1 warmups...    
2022-12-01 16:46:30 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:46:30 Executing block 1 times    
2022-12-01 16:46:30 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:46:30 Executing a balances::transfer_keep_alive extrinsic takes[ns]:
Total: 2148076
Min: 2148076, Max: 2148076
Average: 2148076, Median: 2148076, Stddev: 0
Percentiles 99th, 95th, 75th: 2148076, 2148076, 2148076    
2022-12-01 16:46:30 [0]  generated 1 npos voters, 1 from validators and 0 nominators    
2022-12-01 16:46:30 [0]  generated 1 npos targets    
2022-12-01 16:46:30 Took active validators from set with wrong size    
2022-12-01 16:46:30 Took active validators from set with wrong size    
2022-12-01 16:46:30 Took active validators from set with wrong size.    
2022-12-01 16:46:30 Took active validators from set with wrong size    
2022-12-01 16:46:43  Initializing Genesis block/state (state: 0x19ee…acdb, header-hash: 0xbf52…a822)    
2022-12-01 16:46:43  Loading GRANDPA authority set from genesis on what appears to be first startup.    
test benchmark_extrinsic_works has been running for over 60 seconds
2022-12-01 16:46:55  Creating empty BABE epoch changes on what appears to be first startup.    
2022-12-01 16:46:55 Essential task `txpool-background` failed. Shutting down service.    

[...] 

2022-12-01 16:49:27 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:27 Per-extrinsic execution overhead [ns]:
Total: 9205765
Min: 1458056, Max: 2569258
Average: 1841153, Median: 1687580, Stddev: 411441.5
Percentiles 99th, 95th, 75th: 2569258, 2569258, 1998034    
2022-12-01 16:49:27 Writing weights to "/tmp/.tmpukovTg/extrinsic_weights.rs"    
2022-12-01 16:49:27 [0]  generated 1 npos voters, 1 from validators and 0 nominators    
2022-12-01 16:49:27 [0]  generated 1 npos targets    
2022-12-01 16:49:27 Took active validators from set with wrong size    
2022-12-01 16:49:27 Took active validators from set with wrong size    
2022-12-01 16:49:27 Took active validators from set with wrong size.    
2022-12-01 16:49:27 Took active validators from set with wrong size    
2022-12-01 16:49:37  Initializing Genesis block/state (state: 0x90f5…9992, header-hash: 0x6556…b1be)    
2022-12-01 16:49:37  Loading GRANDPA authority set from genesis on what appears to be first startup.    
test benchmark_overhead_works has been running for over 60 seconds
2022-12-01 16:49:47  Creating empty BABE epoch changes on what appears to be first startup.    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 Essential task `txpool-background` failed. Shutting down service.    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 Running 5 warmups...    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 Executing block 5 times    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 Per-block execution overhead [ns]:
Total: 74899660
Min: 13700020, Max: 18086693
Average: 14979932, Median: 14000104, Stddev: 1642355.19
Percentiles 99th, 95th, 75th: 18086693, 18086693, 15218890    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 Writing weights to "/tmp/.tmpumO2Ak/block_weights.rs"    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 Running 5 warmups...    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 Executing block 5 times    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:47 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:48 Building block, this takes some time...    
2022-12-01 16:49:48 Extrinsics per block: 5    
2022-12-01 16:49:48 Running 5 warmups...    
2022-12-01 16:49:48 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:48 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:48 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:48 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:48 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:48 Executing block 5 times    
2022-12-01 16:49:48 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:48 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:48 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:48 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:48 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:49:48 Per-extrinsic execution overhead [ns]:
Total: 6517901
Min: 1054132, Max: 1551289
Average: 1303580, Median: 1334773, Stddev: 211142.12
Percentiles 99th, 95th, 75th: 1551289, 1551289, 1510116    
2022-12-01 16:49:48 Writing weights to "/tmp/.tmpumO2Ak/extrinsic_weights.rs"    
2022-12-01 16:49:48 Took active validators from set with wrong size    
2022-12-01 16:49:48 Took active validators from set with wrong size    
2022-12-01 16:49:48 Took active validators from set with wrong size.    
2022-12-01 16:49:48 Took active validators from set with wrong size    
2022-12-01 16:49:58  Initializing Genesis block/state (state: 0x2a6d…a321, header-hash: 0xd5b3…562d)    
2022-12-01 16:49:58  Loading GRANDPA authority set from genesis on what appears to be first startup.    
2022-12-01 16:50:08  Creating empty BABE epoch changes on what appears to be first startup.    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 Essential task `transaction-pool-task-0` failed. Shutting down service.    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 Essential task `transaction-pool-task-1` failed. Shutting down service.    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 Essential task `txpool-background` failed. Shutting down service.    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 Essential task `basic-block-import-worker` failed. Shutting down service.    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 Running 5 warmups...    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 Executing block 5 times    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 Per-block execution overhead [ns]:
Total: 40636642
Min: 7998039, Max: 8340508
Average: 8127328, Median: 8123421, Stddev: 125547.9
Percentiles 99th, 95th, 75th: 8340508, 8340508, 8169301    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 Writing weights to "/tmp/.tmpGAgaPp/block_weights.rs"    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 Running 5 warmups...    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 Executing block 5 times    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 Building block, this takes some time...    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 Extrinsics per block: 5    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 Running 5 warmups...    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 Executing block 5 times    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 Per-extrinsic execution overhead [ns]:
Total: 6334846
Min: 1069196, Max: 1617444
Average: 1266969, Median: 1081994, Stddev: 239853.73
Percentiles 99th, 95th, 75th: 1617444, 1617444, 1496373    
2022-12-01 16:50:08 Writing weights to "/tmp/.tmpGAgaPp/extrinsic_weights.rs"    
test benchmark_overhead_works ... ok

test result: ok. 2 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 89.02s

     Running tests/benchmark_storage_works.rs (target/debug/deps/benchmark_storage_works-4795d37400fcf997)

running 1 test
Error: 
   0: Invalid input: Compile with --features=runtime-benchmarks to enable storage benchmarks.

Backtrace omitted. Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display it.
Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=full to include source snippets.
test benchmark_storage_works ... FAILED

failures:

---- benchmark_storage_works stdout ----
thread 'benchmark_storage_works' panicked at 'assertion failed: benchmark_storage(\"rocksdb\", base_path).success()', tests/benchmark_storage_works.rs:31:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace


failures:
    benchmark_storage_works

test result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.03s

error: test failed, to rerun pass `--test benchmark_storage_works`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try again but [follow the steps in the `hacking on polkadot`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot#hacking-on-polkadot) section. You are probably missing some dependencies

Comment: yeah it seems like Substrate is a dependency for Polkadot to work. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/6376 should fix this.
Sorry for the inconvenience.

In the meantime to make it pass you can use the same command that [the CI](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/71a0fadd627e97b5a71c3cc6fa2aefda14328c19/scripts/ci/gitlab/pipeline/test.yml#L25) uses:

```bash
cargo test --workspace --profile testnet --verbose --locked --features=runtime-benchmarks,runtime-metrics
```